# C++ Program to Scramble String Phrases

Tags: c++, string

I'm writing a program to scramble lines that are read in through a string. The phrases are these:

alternate interior angles

pythagorean theorem

right triangle

base angles

side angle side

I want to scramble each individual word, not the entire phrase, but keep each phrase on its own line (using the getline function). After each phrase I'll output underscores corresponding to the length of the phrase, with spaces between each underscore and a double space after underscores corresponding to the last letter of a word in the phrase.

The function I have to scramble words individually:

```
void scramble (apstring w)

{
srand (time(NULL));
apstring orig = w;
for(int i=0; i<w.length(); i++)
{
    int newSpot=rand()%w.length();
    char temp = w[i];
    w[i]=w[newSpot];
    w[newSpot]=temp;
}
while (orig == w);
```

I'm wondering how I would go about searching through each line for spaces after a

```
        getline(fin, phrase);
```

and sending each word individually through the scrambler, but outputting the correct spacing in the outputted phrase, along with the correct number of underscores after the word. I think I need to read the words into substrings, and possibly "purge" the string using something like this:

```
apstring purgeString(apstring word)
{
apstring newWord = "";
for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
{
    if (isalpha(word[i]))
        newWord += word[i];
}
return newWord;
}
```

Any help or suggestions would really be appreciated, this has been stumping me for a little while now.

Comment: Just a side note:  You should only call srand(time(NULL)) once, at the beginning of your program's run, rather than inside scramble().  Otherwise you will likely get the same random-values sequence every time scramble() is called (assuming your program completes in less than one second).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, perhaps something like this (pseudocode since I'm not familiar with the apstring class):

```
apstring theWholeLine = "This is a sentence with some words";
apstring curWord;
for (int i=0; i<theWholeLine.length(); i++)
{
   char nextChar = theWholeLine[i];

   if (isalpha(nextChar)) 
   {
      curWord += nextChar;
   }
   else if (curWord.length() > 0)
   {
      cout << "Time to scramble the next word: " << curWord << endl;
      curWord = "";
   }
}
if (curWord.length() > 0)
{
   cout << "Time to scramble the final word: " << curWord << endl;
}
```

(You'd replace or augment the cout lines with code to do the appropriate per-word scrambling and printing, of course)

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `std::stringstream` with your `phrase` and read each individual word (whitespace delimited) from it like this:

```
std::stringstream ss(phrase);
std::string word;
while (ss >> word) {
   // ... process word
}
```

I noticed you're dealing with individual characters and C functions. While this isn't necessarily a bad approach, here's how I would take a step back and let C++11 do the heavy lifting:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

// obtain a seed from a random_device for random number generator
std::random_device seed;
std::minstd_rand rng(seed());

std::string shufflePhrase(const std::string& phrase)
{
    std::string shuffledPhrase;
    std::string underscores;
    std::stringstream ss(phrase);
    std::string word;

    while (ss >> word) {

        // <algorithm> has a nice shuffle function that works on all iterable types
        std::shuffle(word.begin(), word.end(), rng);
        shuffledPhrase += word + ' ';

        // Add an underscore and space for each letter in the word
        for (const auto& letter : word) {
            underscores += "_ ";
        }
        underscores += ' ';
    }

    // Combine our shuffled phrase and underscores. We strip off the last 2 spaces.
    return shuffledPhrase + underscores.substr(0, underscores.size()-2);
}
```

Now that we have this function, we can call it like this:

```
std::cout << shufflePhrase("alternate interior angles") << std::endl;
```

Possible output:

```
nateaerlt ietnorri nlages _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _  _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _  _ _ _ _ _ _
```